# How to display JSON into UILabel using UIPickerView in Swift 3.0?

Tags: json, swift3, uipickerview

I have these JSON output using PHP.

```
[
    {"number":"001","name":"MIKE"},
    {"number":"002","name":"JOSH"}
]
```

In Swift, I managed to select **"name"** value and display it into UIPickerView like below.

**DropdownJSON.swift**

```
import UIKit

class DropdownJSON: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var dropdownTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var dropdownPV: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet var numberLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var nameLbl: UILabel!

    var persons = [Person]()

    struct Person {
        var number:String
        var name: String

        init?(dict: [String:Any]) {
            guard let number = dict["number"] as? String, let name = dict["name"] as? String else {
                return nil
            }
            self.number = number
            self.name   = name
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getDropdownJSON()
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.persons.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return persons[row].name
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.numberLbl.text      = self.persons[row].number
        self.nameLbl.text        = self.persons[row].name
        self.dropdownPV.isHidden = true
        self.dropdownTxt.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == self.dropdownTxt{
            self.dropdownPV.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    func getDropdownJSON() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/DropdownJSON.json")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error != nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            if let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [[String:Any]] {
                self.persons = array.flatMap(Person.init)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dropdownPV.reloadAllComponents()
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

But my goal is to display JSON output **"number" into numberLbl** and **"name" into nameLbl** in **function pickerView (didSelectRow)**.

The reason is I want to post the numberLbl only later on. nameLbl is just to display on the screen page.

Is it possible ? Appreciate if someone can help on this matters.

**UPDATE**

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to use `URLSession.dataTask` to get response from `URL` instead of `NSData(contentsOf:)`. Also in Swift 3 use native `URL` and `Data` instead of `NSURL` and `NSData`.

Now the problem is you are not storing the `number` value form dictionary. The simplest way to manage this situation is to create `struct` and store both `number` and `name` value with it. After that create Array of that struct instead of Array of `AnyObject`.

```
struct Person {
    var number:String 
    var name: String 

    init?(dict: [String:Any]) {
        guard let number = dict["number"] as? String, let name = dict["name"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Now declare one array of struct `Person` and with your `getDropdownJSON` method add data with in it.

```
var persons = [Person]()

func getDropdownJSON() {
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/getDropdownJSON.json")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [[String:Any]] {
            self.persons = array.flatMap(Person.init)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                dropdownPV.reloadAllComponents()
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Now in `PickerViewDelegate` method use this array to fill its component.

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return self.persons.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return persons[row].name
}
```

Now in `didSelectRow` you need to simply access array object and you will be get the `number` and `name` both.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if row >= self.persons.count { 
        return
    }

    self.numberLbl.text = self.persons[row].number
    self.nameLbl.text = self.persons[row].name
    self.dropdownPV.isHidden = true
    self.dropdownTxt.resignFirstResponder()
}
```