# How to display JSON value in UItableView and separate the value into UILabel in Swift 3.0?

Tags: json, uitableview, struct, swift3

I have these JSON value contains id, name and email.

```
[
    {"id":"101", "name":"Tony",  "email":"tony@mail.com"},
    {"id":"102", "name":"Billy", "email":"billy@mail.com"}
]
```

So far, in Swift 3.0, I managed to **display output into UITableView** manually and **display output into UIButton**.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // Outlet
    @IBOutlet var deptLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var selectBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var idNumberLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var nameLbl: UILabel!

    // Variable
    let array = ["Billy","Dale","Sheila","Thomas","Tony"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableview.isHidden = true
    }

    // Table
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        selectBtn.setTitle(cell?.textLabel?.text, for: .normal)
        self.tableview.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func selectName(_ sender: Any) {
        self.tableview.isHidden = !self.tableview.isHidden
    }

}
```

What I want to achieve is :

1. I want to select **"id and name"** only on JSON value above.
2. Display JSON **"name"** into UITableView.
3. And display JSON **"id"** into UILabel **idNumberLbl** and JSON **"name"** into UILabel **nameLbl**.

I notice that when using pickerView, we can use struct to break json value into separate output but i cannot relate it when using table view.

[How to display JSON into UILabel using UIPickerView in Swift 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941242/how-to-display-json-into-uilabel-using-uipickerview-in-swift-3-0)

Can someone help ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `yourJsonArray` with your array, And with some changes I past your code

```
    import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // Outlet
    @IBOutlet var deptLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var selectBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var idNumberLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var nameLbl: UILabel!

    var yourJsonArray = NSArray()


    // Variable
    let array = ["Billy","Dale","Sheila","Thomas","Tony"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableview.isHidden = true
    }

    // Table
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return yourJsonArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = (yourJsonArray.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "name") as? String
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        let title = (yourJsonArray.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "name") as? String

        selectBtn.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        self.tableview.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func selectName(_ sender: Any) {
        self.tableview.isHidden = !self.tableview.isHidden
    }

}
```

Comment: tq for the feedback . i'll try it first

Comment: it did not work . . . can you update your code on how to apply struct into UItableview ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JSON Array with your array and using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

// Outlet
@IBOutlet var deptLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var selectBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var idNumberLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var nameLbl: UILabel!

// Variable
let array = ["Billy","Dale","Sheila","Thomas","Tony"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableview.isHidden = true
}

// Table
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = UserModel(array[indexPath.row])
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = data.title // get id by data.id
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    selectBtn.setTitle(cell?.textLabel?.text, for: .normal)
    self.tableview.isHidden = true
}

@IBAction func selectName(_ sender: Any) {
    self.tableview.isHidden = !self.tableview.isHidden
}
```

}

U can using `struct` with [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

struct UserModel {
    var name:String?
    var id:String?
    init(json:JSON) {
        name = "\(json["name"])"
        id = "\(json["id"])"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . :) . .